# Force a relative path in open file dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I want my application to allow file attachments, however, I don't want to allow local files to be attached. Obviously, they won't be valid paths on other machines.

Is there anyway I can force the path in an open file dialog to be relative?

I was hoping for a devexpress control that does that, but I can work with the regular Open File Dialog if it's possible.

I can also work with the possibility of only allowing the attachments of URL's.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
fileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, @"YOUR_SUB_DIRECTORY_NAME");
```

Comment: This would be a good solution as the starting path is relative, but this still allows the user to select a local path. Is there any way to force the path to be relative or to allow attachments of url's for example?

Comment: Perhaps do validation on the Open/Save button click event to verify the files path.